# cloudflare serve files from origin server without ssl

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I want to serve files from A server with cloudflare.
I cannot disable SSL on A server. Simply I pointed my domain to A server. When I type https://example.com chrome says that Your connection is not private.

Is it possible to make cloudflare serve files from A server over http not https?

Or can I make cloudflare to use a different SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare has a few different SSL options:

[image: CloudFlare SSL Modes]

[CloudFlare's `Flexible SSL`](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl) will allow communication between the client and CloudFlare over HTTPS whilst the connection from CloudFlare to the origin is over HTTP.

In addition to this, if the certificate is just unsigned but still returns the correct website files you can actually utilise `Full SSL` (but not `Full (Strict)`). By contrast `Full (Strict)` will require a signed certificate from the origin to CloudFlare.